# Grub 2 fails to open luks container with strong password

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, luks, dm-crypt

I've encrypted my /boot partition with dm-crypt in a luks container. I've added a strong password to the slot #0 of the luks container.

Now I can open the container from a live CD successfully but not from Grub.

I tried to put a weak password instead (4 letters) and it works with Grub.

My strong password is 20 characters long, with letters, digits and punctuation in it.

It's not the first time I'm doing this kind of setup, but I've never encountered such an issue before.

EDIT: I use the default keymap.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a keymap problem? Try a password with only letters (it's [easier to memorize for a given strength anyway](https://xkcd.com/936/)) — without QWAZM if you use a French keyboard.

Comment: Well, when I'm dropped in the Grub shell, it seems to be qwerty us. I succeed to type the password in clear in the shell. Do you know if Grub could erroneously change the keymap just for the password prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation is a problem, really. Something in your password makes a special combination which marks the end of the password. Try a longer password, but with letters and digits only.
It is a general advice, not just for Grub. Many older security tools have problems with punctuation, especially slashes.